# Invisible mesh in Drake from obj

Tags: drake

Can someone explain why this mesh is invisible?

It shows up in meshlab.

But not in Drake visualizer.

Here is round.obj:

```
v -0.0381 -0.0381 0.0762
v 0.0381 -0.0381 0.0762 
v 0.0381 0.0381 0.0762 
v -0.0381 0.0381 0.0762 
v 0.0762 0.0762 0.0381 
v -0.0762 0.0762 0.0381 
v -0.0762 -0.0762 0.0381 
v 0.0762 -0.0762 0.0381 
v 0.0762 -0.0762 -0.0381 
v 0.0762 0.0762 -0.0381 
v -0.0762 -0.0762 -0.0381 
v -0.0762 0.0762 -0.0381 
v 0.0508 0.0508 -0.0762 
v -0.0508 0.0508 -0.0762 
v 0.0508 -0.0508 -0.0762 
v -0.0508 -0.0508 -0.0762 
vn 0 0 1 
vn 0 0.707107 0.707107 
vn -0.707107 0 0.707107 
vn 0 -0.707107 0.707107 
vn 0.707107 0 0.707107 
vn 1 0 3.64246e-16 
vn 0 -1 0 
vn -1 0 0 
vn 0 1 0 
vn 0 0.83205 -0.5547 
vn 0 0 -1 
vn -0.83205 0 -0.5547 
vn 0 -0.83205 -0.5547 
vn 0.83205 0 -0.5547 
f 1//1 2//1 3//1
f 3//1 4//1 1//1
f 5//2 6//2 4//2
f 4//2 3//2 5//2 
f 6//3 7//3 1//3
f 1//3 4//3 6//3 
f 7//4 8//4 2//4
f 2//4 1//4 7//4 
f 5//5 3//5 2//5
f 2//5 8//5 5//5 
f 5//6 8//6 9//6
f 9//6 10//6 5//6 
f 8//7 7//7 11//7
f 11//7 9//7 8//7 
f 7//8 6//8 12//8
f 12//8 11//8 7//8 
f 6//9 5//9 10//9
f 10//9 12//9 6//9 
f 12//10 10//10 13//10
f 13//10 14//10 12//10 
f 14//11 13//11 15//11
f 15//11 16//11 14//11 
f 11//12 12//12 14//12
f 14//12 16//12 11//12 
f 9//13 11//13 16//13
f 16//13 15//13 9//13 
f 10//14 9//14 15//14
f 15//14 13//14 10//14
```

I loaded the mesh with the following code. I tried using convex shape, and mesh shape. I wonder if drake only accepts very specific format for the faces without the normals?

```
   inertia = pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia.SolidBox(1, 1, 1)
                mesh_shape = Mesh(str(ROOT_PATH / mesh_path_list[body_idx]), scale=scale_factors[body_idx])
                name = f"polytope_{body_idx}"
                instance = self.plant.AddModelInstance(name)
                H = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix(np.eye(3)), np.zeros(3))

                body = self.plant.AddRigidBody(
                    name, instance,
                    SpatialInertia(mass=mass,
                                   p_PScm_E=np.array([0., 0., 0.]),
                                   G_SP_E=inertia))

                geom_id = self.plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
                        body, H,
                        cv_shape, name,
                        pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction(mu, mu))


                self.plant.RegisterVisualGeometry(body, H, mesh_shape, name, color)
```

This similar file works:

```
v 0.03771961 -0.01979346 0.08371267
v 0.03771961 -0.01979346 -0.08371267
v 0.03771961 0.01979346 0.08371267
v 0.03771961 0.01979346 -0.08371267
v -0.03771961 -0.01979346 0.08371267
v -0.03771961 -0.01979346 -0.08371267
v -0.03771961 0.01979346 0.08371267
v -0.03771961 0.01979346 -0.08371267
f 1 3 7
f 5 1 7
f 6 1 5
f 6 2 1
f 5 7 6
f 6 7 8
f 4 3 1
f 1 2 4
f 4 7 3
f 8 7 4
f 2 6 4
f 4 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The two OBJ files seem to be well-formed. Just like Meshlab, Blender consumes them perfectly happily. More particularly, meldis also consumes it happily. The "invisible" mesh looks like the image below:

[image: Visualization of "invisible" obj in meldis]

I'm not sure why `drake_visualizer` isn't playing along. But `drake_visualizer` is being retired. The simple replacement for you today is to use meldis (`bazel run //tools:meldis`).

Comment: `python3 -m pydrake.visualization.meldis` (see https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.meldis.html)